# How to setup QGIS Server plugins on Windows?

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-server

I want to setup a QGIS-Server with plugins on Windows10.
I installed QGIS-Server, QGIS-Desktop and XAMPP as the Apache-Server.

I downloaded the [HelloServer Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/HelloServer/version/1.1/), unziped it and put it in my plugins folder to test if it works.

My Apache httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so


ServerRoot "C:/xampp/apache"
Listen 80
ServerAdmin postmaster@localhost
ServerName localhost:80

Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"

SetEnv QGIS_PREFIX_PATH "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-ltr"
SetEnv GDAL_DATA "C:\OSGeo4W\share\gdal"
SetEnv PYTHONHOME "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39"
SetEnv PATH "C:\OSGeo4W\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt5\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem"
SetEnv QT_PLUGIN_PATH "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-ltr\qtplugins;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt5\plugins"
FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_PLUGINPATH "C:\OSGeo4W\server\plugins"

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/bin/"

<Directory "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/bin">
    SetHandler cgi-script
    AllowOverride None
    Options ExecCGI
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

My problem is, on this request:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=HELLO
```

I get this respone:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.3.0">
<ServiceException code="Service configuration error">Service unknown or unsupported. Current supported services (case-sensitive): WMS WFS WCS WMTS SampleService, or use a WFS3 (OGC API Features) endpoint</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

And i get this errors in my Apache-Logfile:

```
[Sun May 22 20:58:41.825564 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 8368:tid 1892] [client ::1:60584] AH01215: Warning 1: Unable to find driver ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.\r: C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe
[Sun May 22 20:58:41.825564 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 8368:tid 1892] [client ::1:60584] AH01215: Warning 1: Unable to find driver ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.\r: C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe
[Sun May 22 20:58:41.825564 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 8368:tid 1892] [client ::1:60584] AH01215: Warning 1: Unable to find driver JP2ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.\r: C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe
[Sun May 22 20:58:41.825564 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 8368:tid 1892] [client ::1:60584] AH01215: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db\r: C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe
[Sun May 22 20:58:41.825564 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 8368:tid 1892] [client ::1:60584] AH01215: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db\r: C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe
```

Does anyone know how to configure the Apache on Windows so QGIS-Server is able to use Plugins?

**Solution:**
I uninstalled and deleted all of QGIS and all Python versions. Then i reinstalled QGIS-Desktop and Server and in my httpd.conf i changed FcgidInitialEnv to SetEnv and now it works.

Comment: What service are you expecting to be served by `http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=HELLO` and why?

Comment: HELLO is a service from the HelloServer plugin and should response with "HelloServer!" if everything works fine. It is just to test if the configuration works.

Comment: I see! Have you tried with barebone minimal configuration of the webserver? There is so much configuration in your post, it is hard to see what might be the issue.

Comment: OK, i deleted my vhost and edited my httpd.conf to a minimum. With this config WFS and WMS are working, but i have the same error with the plugin.

Comment: Is your QGIS_PLUGINPATH correct and do the files' permissions match the requirements of the webserver process/user?

Comment: The webserver user is an admin user and has full control. My QGIS_PLUGINPATH is set correct and at this path is the folder of the Plugin which contains the .py files.

Answer (score 0):

Same behavior on Linux containerized deployment with NGINX. That should be to move param QGIS_PLUGIN PATH from fastcgi_param block at nginx conf file to Dockerfile in same place with other QGIS enviroment variables, it will look like:

```
ENV QGIS_PLUGINPATH your/plugins/directory/path
```